# Intra-City Hotel Selection

Tags: usa, hotels

Context:
I am attempting to find an accommodation on the route between two near points, in a major city in the USA. They are separated by less than 5 miles. I arrive at a bus stop, and must find a place to stay for a day. I will arrive late at night, so I would like to find a hotel near my origin. I need to go to a different bus stop, a short distance away, that does not open until the next day. Simply waiting outside is not an option.

Problem:
I cannot find any such place within my budget, that is near my origin, or even near my destination. Is there a better way than what I have been doing to find accommodations?

What I have done to research the problem:
I have put my origin and destination into search engines, with a query to find hotels near the route. All the results are out of my price range. When I try to use an accommodation website, the results given are outside of the distance I am willing to go.

This is not a shopping question because I am asking "I am attempting to do x. How can I have greater success?"

Comment: I'm not really sure how we can help you. Your question boils down to "I would like a hotel very close to some location (which could be in any "major city" in a big country) and all the ones I've found are more expensive than I'd like." While I sympathize, I'm not sure what kind of specific advice would be of practical use to you. You can continue to look for cheaper accommodation (maybe there's a hostel or AirBnB room or couchsurfing opportunity or something), broaden your search to hotels farther away, increase your budget, try other dates when it may be cheaper, or make other travel plans.

Comment: I suppose I was interested in finding out if others have more robust ways of locating accommodations.

Comment: Alas, there's no ITA Matrix for accommodations. We are as screwed as everyone else.

Comment: So you want to find a cheap hotel within 5 miles radius from a major city in the USA?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do. Hotel pricing is not nearly as algorithmic as flight, which means no hidden city fares, massive comparison searches, etc.

If your searches have yielded nothing, then just sort by lowest price and make room in your budget.

That being said, there are still some things you can do.

AirBnB is a good option, but it's uncertain how much cheaper your stay could get with a rigid set of parameters. Couchsurfing opportunities and hostels could also get your closer to your budget, but these are also hit and miss.

If your budget cannot change at all, consider changing your travel dates, itinerary, or maybe broaden your search and take a bit more time to travel to the next bus stop.